# Javascript to change button text back and forth using bootstrap 4 & fontawesome icons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 to create a button with a dropdown menu. The functionality I need is that the button when closed contains the word open and a fontawesome icon beside it. When opened it should say close with an icon beside it.

I'm currently trying this

```js
function toggle() {
  const btn = document.body.querySelector("#dropdownMenu2");

  if (btn.innerText == "Open") {
    btn.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-plus-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "Open";
  } else {
    btn.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-minus-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "Close";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9d2235;
  background-color: #9d2235;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="toggle()">
               <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>                
                Actions
</button>
```

The button changes to close on the first click but never changes back to open when clicked again.

Comment: Your code says: *if text = open, change it "open"*.   As it starts as not "open", it will never be "open"

Comment: `if (btn.innerText != "Open") {` or `if (btn.innerText == "Close") {` depending on what you intend for the *first* click from the loaded value of `Actions` (which is, clearly, neither open nor close)

Comment: Is this referring to the "actions" text? That was supposed to read as open but I forgot to change it. At that point it would start as open..

Comment: It would just affect the first click - after that it would toggle as normal - so either condition would work, just *not* `=="Open"` - if it starts as Open (rather than Actions) then `if = "Open" then make it ="Open"` clearly does nothing.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thanks. I had that code based off of an answer from another question on here. It may be immediately clear to you but some of us are beginners. :)

Comment: Nah, it's just second-set-of-eyes-itis... :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to alter the `dom`.
Why dont you just add a second button with exact details and then just add same class on both the buttons and use jquery(since bootstrap 4 uses jquery) to hide and display other like following

```
$('.buttonClass').toggle();
```